# how to present long text in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I am working on a small app, and I would like to bundle some short text descriptions, maybe with some images, in the help section. What control should I use to place these content? UILabel doesn't look too smart because it doesn't wrap text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used a UIWebView for this sort of thing.

I write out the help in HTML, including images if needs be, and then load it into a UIWebView. It is pretty flexible in terms of layout and fairly trivial to implement:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Instructions" 
                                                                                                         ofType:@"html"]
                                                             isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Just add the file `Instructions.html` to your app and you're good to go.

Comment: Did you know that a method exists called `-[NSBundle URLForResource:ofType:]`. Makes the code easier.